# character array printing output

Tags: c, arrays, string, character

I am trying to understand outputs of printing character arrays and it is giving me variable outputs on ideone.com(C++ 4.3.2) and on my machine (Dev c++, MinGW compiler)

1)

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    char a[] = {'s','t','a','c','k','o'};
    printf("%s ",a);
}
```

It prints "stacko" on my machine BUT doesn't print anything on ideone

2)

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    char a[] = {'s','t','a','c','k','o','v','e'};
    printf("%s ",a);
}
```

on ideone : it prints "stackove" only the first time then prints nothing the subsequent times when i run this program 
on my dev-c : it prints "stackove.;||w" 
what should be the IDEAL OUTPUT when I try to print this kind of character array without any '\0' at the end , it seems to give variable outputs everywhere . please help !

Answer (score 2):

`%s` conversion specifier expects a string. **A string is a character array containing a terminating null character `'\0'` which marks the end of the string**. Therefore, your program as such invokes undefined behaviour because `printf` overruns the array accessing memory out of the bound of the array looking for the terminating null byte which is not there.

What you need is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a[] = {'s', 't', 'a', 'c', 'k', 'o', 'v', 'e', '\0'};
    //                                                    ^
    // include the terminating null character to make the array a string

    // output a newline to immediately print on the screen as
    // stdout is line-buffered by default
    printf("%s\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

You can also initialize your array with a string literal as

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a[] = "stackove";  // initialize with the string literal
    // equivalent to
    // char a[] = {'s', 't', 'a', 'c', 'k', 'o', 'v', 'e', '\0'};

    // output a newline to immediately print on the screen as
    // stdout is line-buffered by default
    printf("%s\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yeah, but what should be the correct output for this ?

Comment: @user2657257 It's undefined behaviour to print an array using `%s` in `printf`. Your program might crash or may give unpredictable result.